# Collada to OpenGL ES data converted for Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, collada

I am undable to find Collada to OpenGL ES data converter like something that gives me vertices, normals, textures etc. for direct use in OpenGL ES from Collada file for the model I want to import into OpenGL ES Android application. The only thing I find are references to Khronos.org website. Does any one know if some game library or any other library out there has such a converter that I could use for my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not for ES but it might help:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/colladaloader/